# Run nightmare by pm2 or something like that on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

How to run `nightmarejs` by pm2 or something like that on the server, because nightmare use the electron and electron need graphic now i'm using `xvfb-run npm start`, but this sol° needs that i stay connected by ssh to the server have you any suggest?

Comment: If you just need to run it once, right before closing your SSH session, then consider [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup). Otherwise, take a look at [systemd](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/nodejs-service-with-systemd/) or [upstart](https://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "screen". "Screen is a console application that allows you to use multiple terminal sessions within one window. The program operates within a shell session and acts as a container and manager for other terminal sessions, similar to how a window manager manages windows." (ref: [info](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server))

```
apt-get install screen

# Create a session called "my_app"
screen -S my_app

# Now you are inside another shell
xvfb-run npm start

# After that, you can detach the screen or close the connection
```

When you want to connect again to the screen, you must use reattach option `-r`.

```
screen -r my_app
```

To list active screens:

```
screen -ls
```

More options and info about `screen` command:

https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Answer (score 3):

Is kind off old but here my answer might be help someone.

1. Create a execution file for pm2 (process.json) with the next.
   Substituting for your specific case.

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "<your_app_name>",
    "script"      : "<your_main.js>",
    "env": {
      "DISPLAY": ":99"
    }
  },
    {
      "name"        : "Xvfb",
      "interpreter" : "none",
      "script"      : "Xvfb",
      "args"        : ":99"
    }]
}
```

2. Move this file to your dist folder or where your main files is stored.
3. Execute `pm2 start process.json`.

You should see both projects executing.

For futher information you can follow [this](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/224#issuecomment-239335488)